# Using lambda inside loop for iterating over columns

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I have a df that has the following structure:

```
ID | M | C1 | C2 | C3  
tt | 23| 23 | 563| 234    
rt | 13| 3  | 32 | 67  
cf | 78| 67 | 90 | 90  
di | 45| 12 | 112| 34
```

I want to iterate over columns and create additional columns as a result of the next operations:

```
additional_column1 = M+1+C1
additional_column2 = additional_column1+1+C2
additional_column3 = additional_column2+1+C3
```

So that the resulted DF will look like this:

```
ID | M | C1 | C2 | C3 | AC1 | AC2 | AD3 
tt | 23| 23 | 563| 234|  47 | 611 | 846
```

I created a for loop, but instead of numbers it fills columns with  **at 0x7f6e81e2c5e0>**

The loop looks as follows:

```
for c in np.arange(start=1, stop=len(df.columns[1:])+1, step=1):
    df['AC'+str(c)] = lambda c: df.columns[c-1].add(0).sub(df.iloc[:, c])
```

Need clue, where I did a mistake. Thanks in advance.

Comment: why are you using lambda at all?

Answer (score 1):

IIUC:

```
for c in np.arange(start=1, stop=len(df.columns[1:])+1, step=1):
    df['AC'+str(c)] = df.iloc[: , c-1].add(0).sub(df.iloc[:, c])
```

Comment: i am not able to generate the expected output for the first column using this, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You can also try `df.cumsum()` on `axis=1` and add the 1 as a range.

```
# df = df.set_index('ID') if ID is not an index
out = df.assign(**df.cumsum(axis=1).add(range(df.shape[1])).iloc[:,1:].add_prefix('A'))
```

---

```
     M  C1   C2   C3  AC1  AC2  AC3
ID                                 
tt  23  23  563  234   47  611  846
rt  13   3   32   67   17   50  118
cf  78  67   90   90  146  237  328
di  45  12  112   34   58  171  206
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this:
(worked for me)

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[23,23,563,234],[13,3,32,67],[78,67,90,90],[45,12,112,34]], columns=['M','C1','C2','C3'])

columns = df.columns

last_col = None
for i, col in enumerate(columns):
    if last_col is None:
        last_col = col
        continue
    df['AC' + str(i)] = df[last_col] + 1 + df[col]
    last_col = 'AC' + str(i)
```